# SonarQube:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start

Tags: java, mysql, sonarqube

I was trying to deploy SonarQube at a local virtual Ubuntu machine.Everything was done.But when I use `/etc/init.d/sonar start` to start sonar server, it failed.

#### web.log:

```
`2017.03.29 01:33:04 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:46)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67)
2017.03.29 01:33:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
`
```

Below are my versions:

- Java : JDK1.8
- SonarQube : 6.3
- Sonar-Runner:2.4
- Mysql : 5.7

#### full web.log:

```
    2017.03.29 01:33:04 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Piledriver][transport_client_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:445)
 org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:364)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.29 01:33:04 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Piledriver][generic][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.29 01:33:04 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2017.03.29 01:33:04 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2017.03.29 01:33:04 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2017.03.29 01:33:04 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.03.29 01:33:04 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:46)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67)
2017.03.29 01:33:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
```

Comment: Are you sure no other service is occupying the port you are trying to start Sonar on?

Comment: Yes，no other service ues 9000.

Comment: @Byan.Li is JAVA_HOME set and on your PATH?

Comment: @luc14n0 yes, done.

Comment: @Byan.Li can you show more rows of web.log?

Comment: @luc14n0 here it is.

Comment: @Byan.Li Could you post the whole log?

Comment: @luc14n0 I fixed it at last. Thanks

Comment: @Byan.Li you should consider either posting your own answer to this question or deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it again,and found that i missed setting `{SONAR_RUNNER_HOME}/bin`on My PATH.